# Group network operations in one swift file - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am developing an iOS app in Swift that consumes REST services (`NSURLSession`, `NSURLRequest`) in all view controllers.

I'd like to group all operations in one Swift class. The class has methods such as `Post`, `Get`, etc. But I found that this then makes it impossible (to me) to update the UI using response results as the calls are in async mode. So to me I have to use `NSURLSession` in each view controller. As a result there is duplicate code scattered in all view controllers.

I am curious how you guys handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)? They are both very good with REST services.
With **AFNetworking** you can easily make asynchronous requests and handle the data synchronously.
**RestKit**, based on AFNetworking, is made specifically for RESTful web services clients and provides great utils. Check it out!

Comment: Please note that both libraries are built with Objective-C. You can just import them in your bridging header if you are using Swift

Comment: Additionally, [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) is AFNetworking's little brother. It is Swift, though is targeted at simpler needs.